# <table> in bootsrap outsize my <div class="spanX">

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Please advise me, I create a three columns by row-fluid, but my table in second column is very large for my `<div class="span7">`
If I made this DIV to `class="container"` or other class - my third div move to bottom, it`s not good for me.

Maybe you give me advice, what I can do for save my third-column-template in one row (screen).

p.s. this is my problem for example, in low resolution table will out-sized:

```
 http:// bit.ly/PIr4kr   - dead link
```

Comment: I`m solve my problem - get a Foundation CSS Framework. In three-column template have a horizontal scroll instead out-size and "one for one" div location.

Answer (score 0):

The `container width` is `960px` so thats y its comes down. You need set `width` of the span. They have default width in bootstrap. so you can set the width whatever you want.

If ex the `span7` width is `640px;` means you can set

```
.span7 {
width: 600px;
}
```

this way you can set the three spans in one row.

Comment: I can`t create fixed span, because my table is dynamically. All pages have a different number of columns. And if second column is very large - this move my third column bottom a second column. Can I range all columns in one row. And scrolling horizontal page for example.

Comment: you can specific by adding the class.

Comment: you can use jquery for this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need transfer in the word "Конфекционированные", for example "Конфекциони-рованные"

also error in the table

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="9">Конфекционированные кабели для систем передачи сигналов</td>
</tr>
```

use colspan="9" instead of colspan="8"

**Update:** more may be reduce `font-size` in `th` and large text `td`